# Send and Recive an array with jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I want to send an array from main.html to test.php file and receive an other array from test.php , but it does not work.plz help me!

## main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        $(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                var SendArrary = [];
                SendArrary[0] = $('#Text1').val();
                SendArrary[1] = $('#Text2').val();
                SendArrary[2] = $('#Text3').val();

                $.get('test.php',
                   SendArrary,
                      function (RecieveArray) {
                          $('#Text1').val(RecieveArray[0]);
                          $('#Text2').val(RecieveArray[1]);
                          $('#Text3').val(RecieveArray[2]);
                      },
                      alert("Ajax Done!!!")
                     )

            });



        });

    --></script>
</head>
<body>
    1<input id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
    2<input id="Text2" type="text" /><br />
    3<input id="Text3" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
</body>
</html>
```

---

## test.php

```
<?php 


$RecieveArray = $_GET['SendArrary'];

$RecieveArray[0] = $RecieveArray[0]."1";
$RecieveArray[1] = $RecieveArray[1]."2";
$RecieveArray[2] = $RecieveArray[2]."3";


print_r($RecieveArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy way:

jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
var callback = function(data){
     data = $.parseJSON(data);
     // do stuff with data
}

$.get("test.php", {
    array: SendArrary
}, callback);
```

php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$arr = explode(",", $_GET['array']);
```

Note: your response NEEDS to be valid JSON, like:

```
["one", "two", "three", 4]
```

With php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
echo("[".implode(",", $yourArray)."]");
```

You might want to look into php JSON toolkits if you want to venture beyond sending and receiving arrays.

Not sure if the php code will work right away, I just looked it up in the manuals, might be an error here or there, but you should get the jest if your read the manual links.